# Can I use Dijkstra's algorithm for longest path in directed cyclic graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have weights from 0 - 10. 0 is the shortest, 10 is longest.
Can I traverse the numbers, 10-x and use Dijkstra for shortest path?

Comment: No, wouldn't work. Longest path is a hard problem. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: why is there a difference if i reverse the weights?

Comment: Try it on an equilateral triangle and see.

Answer (score 2):

In general finding longest path is NP.

> In contrast to the shortest path problem, which can be solved in
>   polynomial time in graphs without negative-weight cycles, the longest
>   path problem is NP-hard, meaning that it cannot be solved in
>   polynomial time for arbitrary graphs unless P = NP.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Answer (score 1):

No. A cyclic graph will have paths of infinite length, and Dijkstra's marking of visited nodes will not allow you to find long paths.

Generally, finding the longest path kind of feels like a very hard problem.